# How to display images with fixed dimensions in ASP.NET after retrieving them from a MySQL database

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

Following are the links which describe connection to MySQL:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asp_net_and_mysql.aspx

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/image_asp.aspx

Here is the code to display image from mysql database:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(db);

    conn.Open();
    string s;
    s = Session["t"].ToString();

    string commantext = "select img_id,img_file,img_type,img_name from image where img_name='"+s+"'";

    //  string commantext = "select img_id,img_file,img_type,img_name from image";
    //  DataSet ds = MySqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(conn, commantext);

    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commantext,conn);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("?img_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = s;

    //  DataTable dt = ds.Tables[0];
    DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

    while(dt !=null)
    {
        Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["img_file"];
        //  Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[1][]  ;                    
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.ContentType = dt.Rows[0]["img_type"].ToString();
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename="
            + dt.Rows[0]["img_name"].ToString());

        Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();
    }          
    conn.Close();               
}


private DataTable GetData(MySqlCommand cmd)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(db);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();

    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }
    catch
    {   return null;
    }
    finally
    {   con.Close();
        sda.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
```

My code to upload image file to mysql database is as below.

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Stream img_strm = File1.PostedFile.InputStream;

```
    int img_len = File1.PostedFile.ContentLength;

    string strtype = File1.PostedFile.ContentType;

    //code snippet to determine image height and width.
    System.Drawing.Image i = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(img_strm);
    int fileheight = int.Parse(i.Width.ToString());
    int filewidth = int.Parse(i.Height.ToString());



     strname = Text1.Value;

    //Session["t"] = strname;

    byte[] imgData = new byte[img_len];
    int n = img_strm.Read(imgData, 0, img_len);
    int result = saveToDb(strname, imgData, strtype);
}


private int saveToDb(string imgName, byte[] imgbin, string imgContenttype)
{



    string db = "server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;password=techsoft";
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(db);
    MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("insert into image(img_name,img_file,img_type) values(?img_name,?img_file,?img_type)", conn);

    //MySqlParameter param0 = new MySqlParameter("?img_id", MySqlDbType.Int16, 20);
    //param0.Value = ;
    //cmd.Parameters.Add(param0);

    MySqlParameter param0 = new MySqlParameter("?img_name", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
    param0.Value = imgName;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param0);

    // MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("?img_file", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
    MySqlParameter param1 = new MySqlParameter("?img_file", MySqlDbType.LongBlob, 10);
    param1.Value = imgbin;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param1);

    MySqlParameter param2 = new MySqlParameter("?img_type", MySqlDbType.VarChar, 45);
    param2.Value = imgContenttype;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(param2);

    conn.Open();

    int num = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    conn.Close();
    return num;
}
```

I have used binary writer to display. Can anybody suggest how to display images in fixed dimensions?

Comment: Not wiki community post. Please edit your quesiton

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the support from rip and The_AlienCoder for their answers. I have found out answer to my own query.

We need to use streams to convert binary data from mysql database. Later graphic library should be used to load the streams. In the meantime we need to resize the image according to our need.

---

```
           protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e){      

            //Create connection to mysql database.
            MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(db);
            conn.Open();
            string s;
            s = Session["t"].ToString();

            string commantext = "select img_id,img_file,img_type,img_name from image where img_name='"+s+"'";

           MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(commantext,conn);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("?img_id", MySqlDbType.Int32).Value = s;

           //create datatable. GetData is a method to fetch the data.
           DataTable dt = GetData(cmd);

           //Get data from database to bytes.
           Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["img_file"];

           //Defining the size to display data.
           int outputSize = 100;


                if (bytes.Length > 0)
                {

                    // Open a stream for the image and write the bytes into it
                    System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes, true);
                    stream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
                    Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(stream);
                    Size new_size = new Size();

                    //resize based on the longer dimension

                    if (bmp.Width > bmp.Height)
                    {
                        new_size.Width = outputSize;
                        new_size.Height = (int)(((double)outputSize / (double)bmp.Width) * (double)bmp.Height);

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        new_size.Width = (int)(((double)outputSize / (double)bmp.Height) * (double)bmp.Width);                            
                        new_size.Height = outputSize;

                    }
                    Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(new_size.Width, new_size.Height, bmp.PixelFormat);
                    Graphics new_g = Graphics.FromImage(bitmap);
                    new_g.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
                    new_g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                    new_g.DrawImage(bmp, -1, -1, bitmap.Width + 1, bitmap.Height + 1);
                    bmp.Dispose();
                    bitmap.Save(Response.OutputStream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                    bitmap.Dispose();
                    new_g.Dispose();
                    stream.Close();
                }
             }

private DataTable GetData(MySqlCommand cmd)
{

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    //String strConnString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager    .ConnectionStrings["conString"].ConnectionString;

    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(db);
    MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.Connection = con;

    try
    {
        con.Open();
        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
        sda.Fill(dt);
        return dt;
    }

    catch
    {            return null;
    }

    finally
    {   con.Close();
        sda.Dispose();
        con.Dispose();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would resize the images on the page being used to display them.  Where are they being displayed?

or

2. I would resize the images at the time they are saved

Comment: They are being displayed on a page directly.
I am very new to asp.net. Could you please tell me how the resizing is done before uploading. U can refer this link:http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/asp_net_and_mysql.aspx
for furthur clarification. It was built by me

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your only challenge is to only scale the images(either before uploading or when retrieving them)...here is some code i use to get scaled dimensions for an image (to fit specific fixed dimensions)...you can stick this somewhere in an imaging class

Note that there are many approaches...

```
public static Size getScaledDimensions( Image img, Int32 maxW, Int32 maxH)
{

    //check if image is already within desired dimensions
    if (img.Height <= maxH & img.Width <= maxW)
    {
        Size orgsize = new Size(img.Width, img.Height);
        return orgsize; // no need to rescale
    }
    else //proceed with rescaling
    {

        int finalH;
        int finalW;

        //use height/width ratio to determine our new dimensions

        double hwRatio = (double)img.Height / (double)img.Width;


             int newW = (int) (maxH/ hwRatio);
            int newH = (int) (hwRatio * maxW);

           //make sure we scale the right dimension
            if (newW <= maxW) // scale width
            {
                finalH = maxH;
                finalW = newW;
            }
            else
            { // scale height
                finalH = newH;
                finalW = maxW;
            }//end if
        Size newsize = new Size(finalW, finalH);

        return newsize;

    }
```

Comment: this is good code but could you please tell me how this could be implemented for binarywriter.